# How to solve Project Euler 23

Tags: python

I've been trying to solve Project Euler #23, but my code is too slow (It also might not work, because I dusted it up from a year ago).
The question is:

---

A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example, the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.

A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.

As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.

Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

---

I've been rewriting this program for ages, got this design, took a break for a year, and modified it a bit.

```
def isAbundant(n):
    return (sum([fctr for fctr in range(1, n) if n % fctr == 0])>n)
abundants=[]

for i in range(28124):
  if isAbundant(i+1):
    abundants.append(i+1)
total=0
for i in range(12,28124):
  for j in abundants:
    if j <= i and not isAbundant(i-j) == True: total += i
print(total)
```

It just lags way too much.

Comment: This code doesn't work, test it with 24 instead of 28124

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify you isAbundant function:

```py
def isAbundant(n):
    return (sum([fctr for fctr in range(1, n//2 +1) if n % fctr == 0])>n)
```

Also the bottom loops would use some optimization:

```py
for j in abundants:
  for i in range(j,28124):  
    if not ((i-j) in abundants): total += i
print(total)
```

Just from the top of my head.

Comment: Tried it, it seems to be faster, but I can't tell (still has no output).

Comment: no need to test `j <= i` in your revised code

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, I overlooked that